# Installing Dot Net Core 2.1 on build server

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to install Dot Net Core SDK 2.1 on our build server (so no Visual Studio) and whenever I then run a build, all I get is

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.

I've installed from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-net-core-2-1-rc-1/

If I do the same on my development machine, it works fine, this can only be down to Visual Studio I assume....

Comment: The link you posted points to a *preview* version though, not the final one. The same blog announces the availability of the final version and included links to the runtime and SDK

Comment: Yeah, it's all installed fine - but when I try and build a solution on that server it says the error message I posted. I'm now downloading through chocolately - see if that helps

Comment: In any case, the .NET Core 2.1 SDK is *not* related to Visual Studio.

Comment: No, DON'T. You used the WRONG LINK. It's fine means IT'S FINE and doesn't need chocolatey or any other trick to work. You installed a PREVIEW version on the server. Or you forgot to install it completeley.

Comment: The *correct* article is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-net-core-2-1/ The correct link to the SDK is https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300

Comment: No joy - still not working. Same error message as I have written above

Comment: If there were any issues with .NET Core 2.1 people would have noticed in the lengthy preview period and the time since RTM. Most likely you *haven't* installed the correct SDK or you targeted the wrong server. Can you run `dotnet --list-sdks` ? What does the output show? If you can't run it, or the output doesn't show at least one version that starts with `2.1.300` you haven't installed 2.1. Did you try installing using the correct SDK link?

Comment: Any chance you could stop being so presumptious??

dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: I'm not presumptious. I'm the only one (still) answering a question without information, that claims something that works for thousands of developers (and me) is broken. Nobody can help without knowing how the build server is configured, which buld server software you use, where or *how* the project is built. People can only *guess* at this point. Did you try running `dotnet build` directly? Did you try RDPing inside the server machine and creating a new dummy project? Perhaps the command used to build uses the wrong SDK *path*? W

Comment: Are you using an older version of TeamCity perhaps? Or the [wrong PATH variable is seen by TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=102498370) ?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK was all installed correctly, but the MSBuildSDKsPath had not been updated to the newer version.

I would expect the installer to do that, seems that's an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: It shouldn't. That's not the path to the SDK, it's [the override to the default SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/SdkResolution/DefaultSdkResolver.cs) when there are multiple SDKs installed side-by-side.

Comment: The env variable that needs checking is `MSBUILD`. The build environment is set by build scripts or development command prompts explicitly. When you have Preview/RC and RTM versions on the same the installer *won't* change the default env variables. I have to type `set MSBUILD=C:\...\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` each time I install a 
new VS update preview and switch it back to `...\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin` when the final Update version is released